# If ALL instances of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following javascript

```
if ( $("#checksquare1").hasClass("checksquareON") && 
$("#checksquare2").hasClass("checksquareON")  &&
$("#checksquare3").hasClass("checksquareON")  &&     
$("#checksquare4").hasClass("checksquareON")  && 
$("#checksquare5").hasClass("checksquareON")  && 
$("#checksquare6").hasClass("checksquareON") ) {.....}
```

However each of the #checksquare have a class of .checksquare

Is there a way of asking if ALL elements with class .checksquare have something

for example. (Obviously this is nonsense, but maybe something similar)

```
$(".checksquare").all.hasClass("checksquareON"){...}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check is there any `checksquare` which does not have `checksquareON` using [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
var $checks = $(".checksquare");
if($checks.not('.checksquareON').length == 0){
}
```

or another way to do the same is to check whether the number of elements having `checksquare` and having `checksquare` and `checksquareON` are the same

```
var $checks = $(".checksquare");
if($checks.filter('.checksquareON').length == $checks.length){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if getting the elements with the added class gives the same amount of elements:

```
if ($('.checksquare').length == $('.checksquare.checksquareON').length) ...
```